# Android bug, how I can apply a fix?

Tags: android, jar

I found an annoying bug in android. This bug is not in my app but in the android java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols class.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170718#makechanges

Someone has modified the android code in order to solve this bug:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/149926/

How can I implement this fix? 
I have to wait that this fix is released through the official channels?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I implement this fix?

You can't, except perhaps by building your own custom ROM with your own custom Android build that has this fix.

If you are using `DecimalFormatSymbols` directly, you could fork it (putting it in your own package), apply the patch, and use your own patched edition. However, that will not work if other framework classes are the ones using `DecimalFormatSymbols`, as they will continue to use the framework copy.

Comment: Unfortunately it's like I thought. Thanks